# How to show image at node & how to plot graph for relation "From & To" in igraph which can work similar to qgraph

Tags: r

```
#Here a plot between from and to column of data frame using qgraph
#We require the same using igraph functionality
if(!require(qgraph)){
install.packages(qgraph)
}else{
require(qgraph)
}
demo_adj <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,'B','X','Y','A'),to=c('A','B','A','Y','1','Y'))
qgraph(demo_adj)
```

How could I plot the same relation using Igraph 
And How could I use image instead of default node in Igraph itself ?